# Create labels for ArcGIS online feature layer and display it in Geocortex Essentials?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, geocortex

How do i create labels for my feature layers (in arcgis online) and display them in Geocortex Essentials. I tried creating labels by adding layers in ArcGIS online map and saved the layer. Also changed symbology for each layer. But in Geocortex Essentials, only symbology for layers is reflected and no labels are drawn.

Any help?